# How to make vertical scrollbar wider on firefox

Tags: firefox, scrollbar

I'm seeking a method of making the vertical scroll bar in Firefox wider so it's easier to grab on a touchscreen PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution to your problem on Mozilla Zine: [How to make the browser scroll bar wider](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=411259).

> Put this code in both `userChrome.css`
>   and `userContent.css`:

```
/* Increase width of VERTICAL SCROLLBAR */
scrollbar[orient="vertical"], scrollbar[orient="vertical"] thumb, scrollbar[orient="vertical"] scrollbarbutton { min-width: 35px !important; -moz-appearance: none !important; }

/* Increase width of HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR */
scrollbar[orient="horizontal"], scrollbar[orient="horizontal"] thumb, scrollbar[orient="horizontal"] scrollbarbutton { min-height: 35px !important; -moz-appearance: none !important; }
```

Comment: Tried it in a JSfiddle, didn't work. Can you please tell me why??
http://jsfiddle.net/2aHeE/530/

Comment: @AtanuCSE, this is code that needs to go in Firefox's own CSS style files. Not CSS rules that apply to the web content. Only Firefox's own scrollbars.

Answer (score 2):

It's no more possible with userChrome.css or userContent.css for new versions of firefox , try this addon:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noiascrollbars/

Comment: Looks like this also no longer works as of Firefox 57. The link displays a big red message: **This add-on is not compatible with your version of Firefox.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xp,
you can still rightclick on desktop
Properties
Appearance
Advanced
Scrollbar and make wider. Mine is 21.

It also will affect Firefox and ALL other programs I use on my XP.

Anelle in Idaho